# Why I can not compile JavaFX program using grade?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

yesterday I created a JavaFX project and I don't know why but when I want to run the app with commands java says:

```
Gradle task : build

Command : java -jar "name_of_the_file.jar"


Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.HelloApplication
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javafx/application/Application
```

but I can run it using gradlew run

> module-info.java file

```
module com.example{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.example ;
    exports com.example;
}
```

> Manifest.MF file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.HelloApplication
```

> build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


jar{
    manifest{
        attributes ('Main-Class' : 'com.example.HelloApplication' )

    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example'
    mainClass = 'com.example.jfx.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

> and project structure

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE90W.jpg)

I am using inteliij idea community and my operating system is windows
I really don't know what is wrong it seems all correct to me. Strange

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your setup.  But it is just a simple HelloWorld application. If it were me, rather than trying to debug it, I would just delete the existing project and create a new project using the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), following the instructions at the link I provided and choosing Maven as the build system rather than Gradle as I find Maven easier to work with and capable enough for basic hello world apps.

Comment: @jewelsea I want to move the program so I compiled it using Gradle I know it is a simple hello world program but I have another program. this is just a simple app so I can show you what's wrong